# Puzzle in Kingdom of the Dead - Darksiders 2

Tags: darksiders-2

On my 1st and 2nd playthrough i'm stuck on this puzzle and i can't stop but imagine there's a room full of treasure chests on the other side.

The puzzle is in the Kingdom of the Dead, starting on the right side when you cross the bridge when you come from the Tree of Death. When you follow the path with some wallruns etc. you come to this point:

[image]

I can use my deathgrip 3 times to make it to the beam in the middle but then my path is blocked by Corruption. I've tried to grab some of the bombs (even tried jumping down to get a bomb during my fall, but to no avail) to clear the path, but with no success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seemed to be rather simple:

1. shoot the bomb, at the same platform of the middle, wooden beam with Redemption to make the Corruption on the platform explode (from the position i'm standing in the screenshot)
2. take the bomb from the middle platform to clear the Corruption from the ceiling
3. use your Deathgrip to get to the end
4. do some hocus pocus with Soul Splitter to get the chest in the end aswell